# If $x^2+ax+b=0$ has a rational root, show that it is in fact an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have tried as follows. Please help to double check the proof! Thank you!

Since $x=p/q$ ($p$, $q$ are integers), $(p/q)^2+(p/q)a+b=0$

So, $(p/q)^2=-b-a(p/q)$

then, $p^2=-bq^2-a(p/q)q^2$

and, $p = \dfrac {q(-bq-a(p/q)q)}{p}$

now, it is clear that $q \mid p$, thus $p/q$ must be an integer.

Comment: How is it clear that $q \mid p$? $(-bq - a(p/q)q)/p$ might not be an integer.

Comment: I see. Would this simplification help? q(-bq^2-ap)/p

Comment: For number-theoretic stuff, you will usually find it clearer if you do not have division in your expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re doing fine up through $p^2=-bq^2-a(p/q)q^2$, but then you go a bit astray. At the end you have something of the form $p=\frac{qn}p$ for an integer $n$; this isn’t a multiple of $q$ unless $\frac{n}p$ turns out to be an integer.

Let’s simplify a bit to make things more readable: $p^2=-bq^2-apq=-q(bq+ap)$. You can certainly conclude from this that $q\mid p^2$. That’s not a contradiction in itself, but you can derive one from it if you further assume that $\frac{p}q$ is in lowest terms. You’ll need the fact that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and $a\mid bc$, then $a\mid c$. (Alternatively, you can use unique factorization here.)

Comment: I knew it has something involved with lowest term, but I couldn't recall the implication of p,q then are relatively prime. That was super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @user1971025: You’re welcome!

Comment: I wouldn't phrase this as a proof by contradiction. You legitimately assume that $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and legitimately derive that $q\mid p^2$. These two conditions together can be shown to imply that $q=\pm1$, so that $\frac pq$ is an integer. No contradiction necessary.

Comment: @Greg: It’s true that no contradiction is necessary; it’s also true that it doesn’t hurt to phrase the argument that way.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: In my opinion, unnecessary proofs by contradiction slow the learning process. Regardless of whether one agrees, I'll point out that your answer claims to reach a contradiction but simply does not: $q$ can well equal $\pm1$.

Comment: @Greg: You’re mistaken: the argument that I was suggesting **does** reach a contradiction, with the assumption that $\frac{p}q$ is a non-integer rational root in lowest terms. The pædagogical claim really doesn’t make much sense. It’s nice when one can be significantly improved, and it’s good to know as a general principle that many proofs by contradiction can be turned into direct proofs, but a valid proof is a valid proof.

Comment: A chacun son goût.

Answer (score 1):

Note you forgot to mention that $a,b$ are integers, otherwise it is clearly false as one may divide by the leading coefficient of any quadratic to put it in that form. By the rational roots theorem all roots of $x^2+ax+b$ are of the form
$$
\pm\frac{\text{factor of constant coefficient}}{\text{factor of leading coefficient}} = \frac{\text{factor of constant coefficient}}{1} = \text{factor of constant coefficient}
$$
which is an integer.

Comment: Sorry! I assumed that every letter in number theory is considered integer. Your idea of using root as factor of coefficient is very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the theorem that if gcd(a,b)=d, then there exist integers x and y such that ax+by=d, it makes the proof much easier. The proof is as follows:

Let $p \over q$ be a solution to $x^2+ax+b=0$, with $gcd(p,q)=1$. We need to show that $q \vert p$.

Then $p^2 \over q^2$+$ap \over q$ + $b =0$.

Multiply by $q^2$:    $p^2 +apq+bq=0$.

Then $q \vert p^2$.

Since $gcd(p,q)=1$, there exist integers m and n such that $pm+qn=1$.

Multiply by p: $p^2m$$+pqn=p$.

Since $q \vert p^2$ and $q \vert pq$, $q \vert p$.